# discord.py / How to make an event for birthdays?

Tags: fixed, discord.py

I am currently making a bot for a server with friends and I want to add a birthday wish automatic message. But even after searching and reading the documentation I can't figure out how to do it.

By the way I don't have a hosting solution yet, so I have to launch it on my pc's startup. That's why I want the bot to check birthdays on startup.

Would appreciate if anyone knows how to do it and could help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can find some examples of birthday bots, [here's a good one](https://github.com/cree-py/birthdaybot/blob/master/birthday.py#L14-L44). It's fairly easy, it's just a loop that checks for birthdays everydays.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but are you sure this example is up to date with discord.py rewrite ?

Comment: It is up to date, you can see it because he uses `ctx.send` to send messages.

Comment: Not sure :/. He hasn't updated his files since 2017...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I've been using discord.py@rewrite for a long time now. You can [compare discord.py and discord.py@rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), you'll notice that he uses discord.py@rewrite

Comment: Well the code gives me "unresolved reference" 'self' and 'guild'. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: I gave you this code as an example of how to do it, since you didn't shared any code in your post. If you have any issue, you can try to make your own code, look at another bot's code or create a "issue" token on this guy's github.

Comment: Sure thing ! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

try using a discord.utils tasks event:

```
import discord
from discord import commands
from discord.utils import tasks
from datetime import date

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    check.start()
    print("Bot Ready")

@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def check():
    today = date.today()
    if today = "2020-07-30":
        for guild in client.guilds:
            if str(guild.id) == "the server id":
                for channel in guild.channels:
                    if str(channel.id) == "your servers b-day channels id":
                        await channel.send("Congrasts Brandon its your b-day")

client.run("token")
```